# Output from char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, output

Can someone explain why I get this odd output? 
Why it doesn't output only one `arr[b]` every time?

**123.in**

```
2
QWERT
YUIOP
ASDFG
HJKLZ
XCVBN
QWERT
YUIOP
ASDFG
HJKLZ
XCVBN
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main() {
int n;
char arr[5][5];
    ifstream source;
    source.open("123.in");

source >> n;
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
    for(int r=0; r<5; r++){
            source >> arr[r];
            cout << arr[r] << endl;
    }
    for(int b=0; b<5; b++)
        cout << " WHY: " << arr[b]<< endl;
}
source.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
QWERT
YUIOP
ASDFG
HJKLZ
XCVBN
 WHY: QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBN
 WHY: YUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBN
 WHY: ASDFGHJKLZXCVBN
 WHY: HJKLZXCVBN
 WHY: XCVBN
```

Why `cout << arr[r] << endl;` and `cout << " WHY: " << arr[b]<< endl;` doesn't output the same code?

Comment: You are encountering UB (undefined behavior). C-like strings need 1 additional character as string termination marker (`\0`), making it so you would need an array of length `6` to store `5` character strings. Since array of arrays is stored on the stack in a single, continuous, block, you will observe the described output (which is still UB, because the values of array contents are undefined, and value, of memory, after the array, is also, undefined).

Comment: The followup to that would be what happens to your program if you (a) include `<string>` and (b) change your `arr` declaration to `std::string arr[5];`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thanks a lot.

Comment: `char arr[5][6];` now works perfect :)

Answer (score 5):

Your data is stored like this:

arr:

```
[0][0]  [0][1] [0][2]  [0][3]  [0][4]  [1][0]  [1][2]  [1][3]  [1][4]  [2][0]  [2][1]  [2][2]  [2][3]  [2][4]  [3][0]  [3][1]  [3][2]  [3][3]  [3][4]  [4][0]  [4][1]  [4][2]  [4][3]  [4][4]  [][]

Q     | W     | E     | R     | T     | Y     | U     | I     | O     | P     | A     | S     | D     | F     | G     | H     | J     | K     | L     | Z     | X     | C     | V     | B     | N
```

When you say that you want to

```
cout << arr[3];
```

that means start displaying my content at "arr[3][0]" and continue till you hit the NULL character. "arr[number]" is really a pointer to another array. Because all of the arrays were initiallized at the same time (char arr[5][5];) it puts the arrays back to back in memory.

For instance, if you do this:

```
cout << arr[0][7] << endl;
```

you will get "I" as the output, because it counts 7 up from the "arr" pointer, which starts at [0][0], which happens to land on "I"

~ Edit per request:

Please note that when you are working with pointers (which an array in c++ really is) that it is easy to disregard the '\0' character that terminates the array. In your example you get lucky that the next character is NULL, but this is not always the case. The string could have continued displaying random characters stored in memory until it happened upon a NULL character. Best practice involves keeping track of the size of the arrays to ensure unintentional results cannot occur.

Comment: This answer would be better, if it described that, in the code sample, the OP has given us, it is not guaranteed that it will ever hit the NULL character.

Comment: On the second thought - it technically will. Since the stream read operation should put it there. But, the very last read operation, should put it past the memory space allocated for the array, which would, if my stack visualization is correct, set the uppermost byte of `source` variable to 0, which may have unexpected (undefined) consequences.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe it depends on the compiler. But generally, they do a good job at sticking NULL at the end

Comment: This looked great until "...when you are working with pointers (which an array in c++ really is) " - no, it isn't. Arrays can *express* as a temporary pointer given the proper context, but they're not pointers. One can easily craft context in C++ where their differences are amplified (by compilation error). The rest of this answer, however, is pretty good.

Comment: @brw59 Yes, but if that NULL character needs to be put outside of the bounds of the array, you are going into an undefined territory. That's what my second comment at the end is all about (granted, that occurred to me after I could edit my original comment).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I understand what you mean, but I think we're misunderstanding each other agreeing on the same thing. When an array is allocated, I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it really allocates one more place in memory than the # that was specified in the initialization. So it takes up 9 char memory slots if I were to do this "char temp[8];", not 8.

Answer (score 0):

C++ expects your C-strings (char arrays) to end in a special "end-of-line" symbol (you can escape it as '\0'). Since you filled each 5-letter string to the brim, it doesn't know when to stop reading. For example, "QWERT" would be represented as 6 characters instead of 5:

'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', '\0'

When cout starts reading it doesn't find that last character, so it keeps reading the following memory positions. In this case, the next row: "YUIOP". And so on.

Comment: Worth noting that following memory positions can be anything. It just happens to be the next row ....."Undefined behaviour"